# FETs: When does Input Capacitance and Gate Charge matter?

Tags: fet

My question is this:

- Besides frequency response (i.e. filter effect), does input capacitance every matter?
- When does gate charge matter?

Obviously these have effects on the graphs in the datasheet, but is there any general behavior each has? (i.e. larger gate charge means X, smaller gate charge means Y).

This has come up because I'm doing a lot of load output stuff (i.e. not fast switching, just having a FET for the sake of reverse polarity protection or output OR-ing), and am wondering if these two characterstics even matter if the FET is only really used in a DC, "almost always on" circuit.

Comment: Whenever (Rs+Rg)*Ciss exceeds/approaches your expected gate rise/fall time.

Comment: Side note: It's called the _Miller Effect_, not the "Filter Effect" :) or I could be wrong... I don't know. I've never heard it be called as such.

Comment: @KingDuken I'm aware of the Miller Effect, I think that has more to do with the internal interactions of capacitances and how they actually change dynamically. When I said "filter effect", I literally just meant the fact that since the the transistor has input capacitance, it will act as a filter for high frequencies (and not let high F pass through). But yeah, cheers :)

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 when you say Rs and Rg, do you mean resistors that are tacked onto the the S and G externally or do you mean the internal Rg and Rs characteristic resistances? (I assume the former, since I'm pretty sure Rg internally of a FET is practically an open-circuit)

Answer (score 7):

> am wondering if these two characterstics even matter if the FET is
>   only really used in a DC, "almost always on" circuit.

Probably not a big worry but, if you are interrupting a load current of several amps and you turn on or off the MOSFET too slowly (100 ms could be too slow), the MOSFET can enter a thermal-runaway situation because the gate-source voltage is below the ZTC threshold. ZTC here stands for "zero temperature coefficient".

What happens is that as the gate reaches a low enough voltage the MOSFET will try and take excessive drain currents and this might spiral out of control. I'm not saying this will be the case in the vast majority of applications of course. Applications such as hot-swapping and eFuses tend to be vulnerable. Constant current generators are also vulnerable.

Most engineers are taught that MOSFETs don't have "the wrong temperature coefficient" but they all do have this "feature" when the gate voltage is below a certain threshold: -

[image]

The ZTC point is where the red circle is. It happens to low power MOSFETs as well as high power ones (like the above device). The points on the graph below a gate voltage of about 3.8 volts are where the temperature coefficient can cause thermal runaway.

So, if you have excessive gate capacitance and you activate the gate through a high resistance you might cause thermal runaway.

Answer (score 2):

It matters a lot in switching regulators for example. In order to minimize losses and maximize efficiency, you need to drive the mosfet gate to saturation as quickly as you can, because most of the losses in a switching regulator happen when the mosfet is in between fully ON and fully OFF. Mosfets with higher gate charge need more current to drive their gate to saturation, and in consequence need a beefier driver. The tradeoff is that ON resistance and power rating have an inverse relationship with gate charge and capacitance. Smaller mosfets with lower gate charge usually can handle a lot less power or have higher RDSon, while larger ones with higher gate charge and capacitance can handle more power and have lower resistance, but need a bigger gate driver.

In the real world, that translates into always trying to find the lowest gate charge mosfet with the lowest Ton and Toff and RDSon that can handle your load for your gate driver's impedance, in order to maximize efficiency and minimize losses. For example, if you are selecting a mosfet to use as an audio signal amplifier, the gate charge and capacitance will have to be matched to the signal's impedance, usually through a bias resistor.

Answer (score 1):

A thumbnail answer is ;

It matters whenever (Rs+Rg)*Ciss exceeds/approaches your expected gate rise/fall time.

### RdsOn ratio from stage to stage also depends on dV/dt

Since Coss*RdsOn tends to be constant for a given family and voltage specs  and Ciss correlates with Coss as R load reduces , R Gate must reduce so there is an optimal ratio and hence number of stages when going from 1mA dynamic input current  to say 1kA. WHen speed matters the Rdson ratio reduces by 100:1 for each driver stage.  When it doesn't matter much, it can be 5000:1  So obvious you need to determine load slew rate for each stage.

Answer (score 0):

Here, they successfully employ the non-linear Coss of power MOSFETs for softswitching to increase efficiency of a converter: [Efficiency Optimization of an Automotive
Multi-Phase Bi-directional DC-DC Converter](https://www.pes-publications.ee.ethz.ch/uploads/tx_ethpublications/waffler_paper_IPEMC09.pdf)

Answer (score -1):

For low VDD/Vt ratios, the ideal is 2.718.

For high Vdd/Vt, the ideal is 5 or higher.

===================================

Various books offer the derivation for low VDD/Vt ratios.

Yet, attempting that (2.718) while optimizing a chain of inverters for driving huge clock lines at high VDD was surprising. The circuit I'd inherited was clearly of the 1:5:25:125 nature, and I had to come to grips with that. Eventually a paragraph in "Current mode analog circuit design" by Tomazou gave some clarity.

The reason has to co with slewrate through the midpoint of the waveform (which other answers discuss). Takes *time* to reach the midpoint (at which time the downstream CMOS inverter will also be quickly slewing but has not yet reached its own midpoint, because the rate of energy movement is finite). Thus each CMOS inverter adds delay because of need to slew to midpoint; minimizing the # of inverters gives minimal delay.

For large VDD/Vt ratios, the slewrate is a big deal.

For small VDD/VT ratios, the need to exceed Vt is a large part of the delay.

[I'm not sure this has led to clarity]

Comment: This matters for minimizing dynamic energy and optimziing Rdson when Vgs=Vdd.  Good point. I usually say Vgs2.5~3x for low logic level drive and Vgs>> 3x  Vgs(th) ( or Vt) for 4V types.

Comment: This answer is a bit too concise and unclear, could you expand a bit more?

Comment: why the downgrade? tony stewart likes it.